# Elapsed time driven Automated Reminder workflow

Tags: workflow, date-time, reminder

Am trying to create a workflow (SP 2013) that checks today's date, checks the date an item was created, and if it is a week old, sends an e-mail to to creator saying "we are still working on your feedback."

Created a column called AgeOfSubmission and set it value = created +7.  Then created a column ItemStatus that defaults to "Open/Not Yet Reviewed"

The List workflow was then created as follows:
[image]

To test, we used created +1 -- that step works.  Nothing else does.  Not sure if this is because:
1) It should have been a site workflow
2) "today" dos not work like I think it should
3) there is no precipitating event to initiate the workflow (settings are both start manually and start when item is created"
4) Some logic snafu.

Ideas on how to solve would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can easily be done by using retention (Library/list settings>information management> enable retention).

Please note that in SP2013 retention only works with 2010 workflows.

You want to add a retention stage that starts after date field created +7 days with the action set to run your workflow.

The result is that after 7 days your workflow will run and do any logic required (such as send an email).